# Flex dispatchEvent to exit an ItemEditor

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, dispatchevent, itemeditor

I have an ItemEditor with a ComboxBox.
To improve user experience, I would like to exit the ItemEditor each time the user select a value in the combobox. So he doesn't have to click outside the cell to validate his choice.

I did this, but it is not working. Why ?

```
        private function comboChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            var dgOrder:DataGrid = owner as DataGrid;
            var dgEvent:GridEvent = new GridEvent(GridEvent.GRID_CLICK);
            dgEvent.preventDefault();
            dgOrder.dispatchEvent(dgEvent);

        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:ComboBox id="ddlCurrency" width="100%" dataProvider="{lstCurrencies}" labelField="CurrencyCode" 
            prompt="Select a currency" change="comboChange(event)"></s:ComboBox>
```

EDIT after Marcx comment :

```
override public function get value():Object {
                trace("get value");
                ddlCurrency.selectedIndex = newCountryID;
            if (ddlCurrency.selectedIndex == -1 || ddlCurrency.selectedItem.CurrencyID == -1){
                updateCurrency(data.OrderID, -1);
                return "";
                } else if ((lstCurrencies[ddlCurrency.selectedIndex as int] as Object).CurrencyCode.toString() != ddlCurrency.selectedItem.CurrencyCode){
                    return oldValue;
                } else {
                    updateCurrency(data.OrderID, ddlCurrency.selectedItem.CurrencyID);
                    return ddlCurrency.selectedItem.CurrencyCode;
                }
            }

private function comboChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                var dgOrder:DataGrid = owner as DataGrid;
                newCountryID = ddlCurrency.selectedIndex;
                dgOrder.setFocus();
            }
```

When I select a value on the dropdownList (it was a combobox before), combochange is called and the ddlCurrency.selectedIndex is the one I have just selected, and once the get value() function is called the same ddlCurrency.selectedIndex is the previous index. It why I save the new Index in a variable to force the new index in get value().

I hope I made my self clear.

Thanks in advance.
Antoine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the focus on the parent element or directly the application...

```
private function comboChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
{
    var dgOrder:DataGrid = owner as DataGrid;
    var dgEvent:GridEvent = new GridEvent(GridEvent.GRID_CLICK);
    dgEvent.preventDefault();
    dgOrder.dispatchEvent(dgEvent);
    // set the focus on the owner component
    dgOrder.setFocus();             
}
```

From the as3docs:

> **spark.components.DataGrid.setFocus():void**
>
> [Inherited] Sets the focus to this component. The component can in turn pass focus to a subcomponent.
>
> **Note:** Only the TextInput and TextArea controls show a highlight when this method sets the focus. All controls show a highlight when the user tabs to the control.

Comment: Hi, it works but I need to keep in a variable the combo selected index, because this goes back to his previous variable just before the get value() function is called.

Comment: I do not understand the problem... please edit the question adding the getvalue function and why you have to keep a variable for the selectedIndex.. thanks